# Can not check emptiness of array at index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in Javascript. It looks like the one below.

`source_array=[["A","B","C"],["A","B","C"],["A","B","C"]]`;

I create it by `source_array.push(anotherArray)`.
During the running of my code i remove entries from the indexes one by one by
`source_array[1].splice(0,1)`. So from `[["A","B","C"],["A","B","C"],["A","B","C"]]` i expect to get `[["A","B","C"],["B","C"],["A","B","C"]]`;

If i do it enough times i should end up with `[["A","B","C"],[],["A","B","C"]]`.

How to properly check if source_array[1] is now empty? It doesnt seem to work for me.

`If (source_array[1] == undefined)` this turns out FALSE instead of TRUE. It gives out FALSE only after i am done removing the items. It works well if i check for `source_array[2] in a source_array[["A","B","C"],["A","B","C"]]`

I think i tried everything i found online.

I feel it will be something basic, but i am an amateour and this...beats me.

Comment: `if (source_array[1].length === 0)` ?

Comment: An empty array is not `undefined`-- you need to check if it's `.length` property is `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the array is empty, it's not undefined.

Always check the array's length property to determine whether a targeted array is empty.

Thus:

```
let arr = [];
let arr2 = ['foo', 'bar'];

arr.length === 0;  // true, empty
arr2.length === 0; // false, populated
```